# Understanding bashrc alias command

Tags: bash, shell

What does this particular alias command do?

```
alias hello='sudo $(history -p \!\!)'
```

I want to understand what history and -p do!

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively

Comment: Your question is not about alias. Is about a command. The history command output is being stored in a var. Is all i can tell you but the easiest is to search for the history command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash keeps track of the commands you run.  This is called your *command history*. The `history` command lets you access and manipulate your command history.

The `-p` flag tells the `history` command to perform *history substitution* on its argument and print the result on standard output.  When performing history substitution, `history` replaces `!!` with the previous command.  In your case, each `!` is escaped as `\!`, presumably because bash lets you set the `!` to be extra-magical and the author of this alias wanted to suppress the extra magic.

When bash sees `$(...)`, it performs *command substitution*.  This means it runs the command between the parentheses, and replaces `$(...)` with the standard output of the command,

The `sudo` command runs its arguments as root.

Thus this alias lets you type `hello` to run your previous command as root.  You will run into trouble if the previous command has quoted whitespace (I think), but usually it should work.

You can get the same effect with (in my opinion) a little less magic by using `fc`:

```
alias hello='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
```

The `fc` command also performs history access and manipulation.  The `-l` flag means “print some history entries”.  The `-n` flag means don't print history entry numbers (just print the commands).  The `-1` (negative one) means print just the most recent history entry.